# My python script is getting stuck on fetching distinct count of a column from hive

Tags: python, count, hive, distinct

```
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) FROM tname")
a= cur.fetchone()[0]
```

And my table has more than 2,500,000,000 records.

Comment: That is a lot of records, is USER_ID an indexed field?

Comment: No. Its not an indexed field.

Comment: Then it is probably just taking a really long time. Can you index the database?

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error in your query. Did you try use fetchall?

```
a= cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: But when I am indiviually trying this query in hive its working fine though it takes an hour to execute. So I am guessing its something wrong with the cursor. Is there a limitation of a high value or something?

Comment: What's happenning is that you have a query with distinct, you losing performance. Try execute this query in database and you see how long to run.

Answer (score 0):

Because USER_ID is not an indexed field, the database must access every row in order to determine all the unique values in that field. This can take a really long time with that many rows. (As you noted running the query in hive takes an hour to execute).

So, if by "hang" you mean you are getting something like the Windows: "This application is not responding." It could be caused by you running this cursor in the main thread. Anything that blocks the main thread for an extended period of time will cause the application to "hang".

Can you give more details on what you mean by the application is getting stuck? How long have you let it run?